# iOS place cursor after word in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a string in a UITextView.

```
NSString *str = @"Hello world. What @are you @doing ?"
```

When I tap on the UITextView the cursor goes where I tap on the string. But I need that, suppose I tap on any character of that textview, the cursor will automatically goes to the end of that word. For e.g, I tap on the character "e" in "Hello", then the cursor will place after "Hello".

How can I do this?

Comment: Try modify `textView.selectedRange`? Get the range (i.e. index) and compute next none white space character?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Cursor behave properly. But is any word contains any special characters (like : hello_01) then the cursor goes on @"_". How can I prevent this? How can I treat this as normal string, so that the cursor goes at the end?

Comment: Exactly, you need to find the next white space yourself, and set the `selectedRange`

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand the concept and underlying structure of a touch device.
Let me explain. 
When you have a textfield/ textview, inside a view and your keyboard is not showing ie. textfield is inactive. The superview might have any number of gesture recognisers other than the textfield.
Hence the OS just detects the touch which will make the UI element become `firstResponder`, or rather Active.
After the textfield is active, OS recognises that the other gesture pattern will come into play in this moment. And in this moment you can tap in any position (or Long tap) and then place ur cursor at any character you want.

Hope you could understand.

Comment: thanx for your answer. But is it possible to do that without long tap or any gesture ? I need it in a single tap.

Answer (score 0):

this should be the default behavior of textview. You not need to do any additional setup for that! If you will long press then only your cursor go at particular character otherwise it will go to end of the word. this is the default behavior.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. Cursor behave properly. But is any word contains any special characters (like : hello_01) then the cursor goes on @"_". How can I prevent this? How can I treat this as normal string, so that the cursor goes at the end?

Comment: no thats not possible i think and why you want to change default behaviour?